# How to create trigger when one rows is updated to update another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have two tables, that has references with ID of products. Tables are like below.

Table 1 :   ID, Rgrupa
Table 2:    ID, Rgrupa

I would like to create trigger, that will update Rgrupa from table 2, when Rgrupa is updated in table 1, for the same ID of product.

I have tried this

```
create or replace trigger test 
after update of rgrupa on table1 
begin 
update table2 t2 
set t2.rgrupa = :new.rgrupa 
where t2.id = :new.id;
end;
```

And ERROR MESSAGE is:
Error: ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Comment: what is stopping you from creating a trigger ? are you getting any error while creating it ?

Comment: Do your tables have the same primary key? If so, can you merge the two tables so you don't need a trigger at all?

Comment: SO is not for questions like "how to do so". Please edit your question by adding what you tried so far and the issue with your code.

Comment: @ Sudipta Mondal  Its stop me nothing, just dont know how to do. I have some idea, like 
create or replace trigger test
after update of rgrupa on table1
begin
update table2 t2
set  t2.rgrupa = :new.rgrupa 
where t2.id = :new.id;
end;
But don't know is this the righy way

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? What do you get from this?

Comment: @Savke: Create the trigger you have given in the comment and see what's happening? If there is any error, you can ask here.

Comment: Why can't you simply try this code and see what happens?

Comment: @Aleksej  I run this code, but not sure is it ok? if it is, i can leave it like this, if is not, than i should do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below structure to create the trigger

```
create table table1 (id int, rgrupa varchar2(100));
create table table2 (id int, rgrupa varchar2(100));

insert into table1 (id,rgrupa) values (1,'A');
insert into table1 (id,rgrupa) values (2,'B');
insert into table1 (id,rgrupa) values (3,'C');

insert into table2 (id,rgrupa) values (1,'A');
insert into table2 (id,rgrupa) values (2,'B');

commit;

select * from table1;
select * from table2;

create or replace trigger sandeeptest after update of rgrupa on table1 for each row
begin
update table2 set rgrupa=:new.rgrupa where id=:new.id;
end;

update table1 set rgrupa='Aa' where rgrupa='A';

update table1 set rgrupa='Cc' where rgrupa='C';
```

Answer (score 3):

If I run your code:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
  2      AFTER UPDATE OF rgrupa
  3      ON table1
  4  BEGIN
  5      UPDATE table2 t2
  6         SET t2.rgrupa    = :new.rgrupa
  7       WHERE t2.id = :new.id;
  8  END;
  9  /
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
```

Oracle clearly says that you have an issue in your code.
If you want to use the `:new`, you need a row-level trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
  2      AFTER UPDATE OF rgrupa
  3      ON table1
  4      FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6      UPDATE table2 t2
  7         SET t2.rgrupa    = :new.rgrupa
  8       WHERE t2.id = :new.id;
  9  END;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Comment: Thank's man. I did't see clearly, and was confused. Now see that  there is no 'for each row' syntax, for row level trigger. Thank's a lot